# API for SQLConnect Library

Tags: objective-c, api, library

I've designed a library for connecting Objective-C (and now Swift) apps to Microsoft SQL Server 2005+.  (I believe there are other databases it works with, but I've only tested with MSSQL.)

[The project is available on Github here](https://github.com/nhgrif/SQLConnect/releases), and while users are fully capable of downloading the uncompiled project, my recommended option is downloading the compiled project along with the necessary headers.

I am interested in a review of the library's API.

Here it is:

## SQLConnect.h

```
@import Foundation;

NSString * const SQLCONNECTION_VERSION_NUM;

#import "SQLConnection.h"

#import "SQLViewController.h"
#import "SQLTableViewController.h"
#import "SQLCollectionViewController.h"
#import "SQLSettings.h"

BOOL isNull(id obj);
id nullReplace(id obj, id replacement);
```

## SQLConnection.h

```
#import "SQLConnectionDelegate.h"
#import "SQLSettings.h"

@interface SQLConnection : NSObject

#pragma mark Properties
/**
 *  Indicates whether or not the database is currently connected
 */
@property (nonatomic,assign,readonly) BOOL connected;

/**
 *  The database server to use.  Supports server, server:port, or server\instance (be sure to escape the backslash)
 */
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *server;

/**
 *  The database username
 */
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *username;

/**
 *  The database password
 */
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *password;

/**
 *  The database name to use
 */
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *database;

/**
 *  Delegate to handle callbacks
 */
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<SQLConnectionDelegate> delegate;

/**
 *  The queue to execute database operations on.  A default queue name is used, but can be overridden.
 */
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSOperationQueue *workerQueue;

/**
 *  The queue for delegate callbacks.  Uses current queue by default, but can be overridden.
 */
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSOperationQueue *callbackQueue;

/**
 *  The character set to use for converting the UCS-2 server results. Default is UTF-8. Can be overridden to any charset supported by the iconv library. 
 *  To list all supported iconv character sets, open a Terminal window and enter:
 *  $ iconv --list
 */
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *charset;

/**
 *  Login timeout, in seconds. Default is 5.  Override before calling connect
 */
@property (nonatomic,assign) int loginTimeout;

/**
 *  Query timeout, in seconds. Default is 5. Override before calling executeQuery:
 */
@property (nonatomic,assign) int executeTimeout;

/*
 *  Tag for the object.  Not used internally at all.  Only used for the user to distinguish which connection is calling the delegate method if wanted.
 */
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger tag;

#pragma mark Initializer methods

- (id)init __attribute__((unavailable("Must initialize with a delegate")));

/**
 *  Returns a SQLConnection instance using the defaults defined in the SQLSettings defaultSettings object
 *
 *  @param delegate Required. An object conforming to the SQLConnectionDelegate protocol for receiving callback messages.
 *
 *  @return SQLConnection object using the SQLSettings defaultSettings
 */
+ (instancetype)sqlConnectionWithDelegate:(NSObject<SQLConnectionDelegate>*)delegate;

/**
 *  Returns a SQLConnection instance
 *
 *  @param server   Required. The database server to use.  Supports server, server:port, or server\instance (be sure to escape the backslash)
 *  @param username Required. The database username.
 *  @param password Required. The database password.
 *  @param database Required. The database name.
 *  @param delegate Required. An object conforming to the SQLConnectionDelegate protocol for receiving callback messages.
 *
 *  @return SQLConnection object
 */
- (id)initWithServer:(NSString*)server
            username:(NSString*)username
            password:(NSString*)password
            database:(NSString*)database
            delegate:(id<SQLConnectionDelegate>)delegate;

/**
 *  Returns a SQLConnection instance
 *
 *  @param server   Required. The database server to use.  Supports server, server:port, or server\instance (be sure to escape the backslash)
 *  @param username Required. The database username.
 *  @param password Required. The database password.
 *  @param database Required. The database name.
 *  @param delegate Required. An object conforming to the SQLConnectionDelegate protocol for receiving callback messages.
 *
 *  @return SQLConnection object
 */
+ (instancetype)sqlConnectionWithServer:(NSString*)server
                               username:(NSString*)username
                               password:(NSString*)password
                               database:(NSString*)database
                               delegate:(NSObject<SQLConnectionDelegate>*)delegate;

/**
 *  Returns a SQLConnection instance
 *
 *  @param settings Required. The settings to use for connecting to the database.
 *  @param delegate Required. An object conforming to the SQLConnectionDelegate protocol for receiving callback messages.
 *
 *  @return SQLConnection object
 */
- (id)initWithSettings:(SQLSettings*)settings delegate:(NSObject<SQLConnectionDelegate>*)delegate;

/**
 *  Returns a SQLConnection instance
 *
 *  @param settings Required. The settings to use for connecting to the database.
 *  @param delegate Required. An object conforming to the SQLConnectionDelegate protocol for receiving callback messages.
 *
 *  @return SQLConnection object
 */
+ (instancetype)sqlConnectionWithSettings:(SQLSettings*)settings delegate:(NSObject<SQLConnectionDelegate>*)delegate;

#pragma mark Working methods

/**
 *  Connects to the SQL database using the current connection settings.
 */
- (void)connect;

/*
 *  An optional alternative to connect.  This method frees the connection info immediately after the connection attempt so it is not kept in memory.
 *
 *  @param server   Required. The database server to use.  Supports server, server:port, or server\instance (be sure to escape the backslash)
 *  @param username Required. The database username.
 *  @param password Required. The database password.
 *  @param database Required. The database name.
 *  @param charset  Optional. The charset to use.  Will default to preset charset if nil is passed.
 */
- (void)connectToServer:(NSString *)server withUsername:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password usingDatabase:(NSString *)database charset:(NSString *)charset;

/**
 *  Executes the provided SQL statement.  Results are handled via the delegate methods.
 */
- (void)execute:(NSString*)statement;

/**
 *  Disconnects from database server
 */
- (void)disconnect;

@end
```

## SQLConnectionDelegate.h

```
@class SQLConnection;

@protocol SQLConnection <NSObject>

/*
 *  Required delegate method to handle successful connection completion
 *  
 *  @param  connection  The SQLConnection instance which completed connection successfully
 */
@required - (void)sqlConnectionDidSucceed:(SQLConnection *)connection;

/*
 *  Required delegate method to handle connection failure
 *
 *  @param  connection  The SQLConnection instance which failed to connect
 *  @param  error       An error describing the connection problem
 */
@required - (void)sqlConnection:(SQLConnection *)connection connectionDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error;

@end

@protocol SQLQuery <NSObject>

/*
 *  Required delegate method to handle successful execution of a SQL command on the server
 *
 *  @param  connection  The SQLConnection instance which handled the execution
 *  @param  results     The results, if any, returned from the database
 */
@required - (void)sqlConnection:(SQLConnection *)connection executeDidCompleteWithResults:(NSArray *)results;

/*
 *  Required delegate method to handle unsuccessful execution of a SQL command on the server
 *
 *  @param  connection  The SQLConnection instance which handled the execution
 *  @param  error       An error describing the execution problem
 */
@required - (void)sqlConnection:(SQLConnection *)connection executeDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error;

@end

@protocol SQLConnectionDelegate <SQLConnection, SQLQuery>

/*
 *  Optional delegate method to handle message notifications from the server
 *
 *  @param  connection  The SQLConnection instance which received the message
 *  @param  message     The message from the server
 */
@optional - (void)sqlConnection:(SQLConnection *)connection didReceiveServerMessage:(NSString *)message;

/*
 *  Optional delegate method to handle error notifications from the server
 *
 *  @param  connection  The SQLConnection instance which received the message
 *  @param  error       The error message from the server
 *  @param  code        The error code from the server
 *  @param  severity    The error severity from the server
 */
@optional - (void)sqlConnection:(SQLConnection *)connection didReceiveServerError:(NSString*)error code:(int)code severity:(int)severity;

@end
```

## SQLSettings.h

```
@import Foundation.NSObject;
@import Foundation.NSString;

@interface SQLSettings : NSObject

/*
 *  Returns a SQLSettings instance
 *
 *  @return SLQSettings object
 */
+ (instancetype)settings;

/*
 *  Returns a shared SQLSettings instance. This object can be used to specify default settings that SQLConnection objects will use when initialized without settings parameters.
 *
 *  @return Default settings object
 */
+ (instancetype)defaultSettings;

/**
 *  The database server to use.  Supports server, server:port, or server\instance (be sure to escape the backslash)
 */
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *server;

/**
 *  The database username
 */
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *username;

/**
 *  The database password
 */
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *password;

/**
 *  The database name to use
 */
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *database;

@end
```

## SQLViewController.h

```
@interface SQLViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL sqlDebugLogging;

- (void)viewDidLoad NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;

@end
```

## SQLTableViewController.h

```
@interface SQLTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL sqlDebugLogging;

- (void)viewDidLoad NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;

@end
```

## SQLCollectionViewController.h

```
@interface SQLCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController

@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL sqlDebugLogging;

- (void)viewDidLoad NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;

@end
```

Presuming you got only these files and the compiled library file, would you feel confident using this library?  Are there any naming issues?  Anything missing?

And if you're wondering about, `NS_REQUIRES_SUPER`, [here's some reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446018/when-a-subclass-overrides-a-method-how-can-we-ensure-at-compile-time-that-the-s/21446076#21446076).

Answer (score 8):

A few notes:

- I feel like some of your properties should have the `readonly` attribute applied to them.  Do we really want the API users to have the ability to change the `username`, `password`, or `server` variables after initialization?

  ```
  @property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *server;
  ```

  If you do really want them to have that ability, I would add a method so that those variables could be set to different values at the same time.
- You have the phrase "Required." in a lot of your `@param` comments.  As a frequent user of many APIs, I always assume that a valid parameter value is required unless told otherwise.  So you only need to tell me what parameters are optional in your documentation (which is just one, that I could see).
- You forgot that little extra `*` on some of your comment lines.  This is important, since this is needed for Doxygen to parse these comment blocks (you are using [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html), correct?).

  ```
  /*  <---- need two * right there
   *
   *  Required delegate method to handle successful execution of a SQL command on the server
   *
   *  @param  connection  The SQLConnection instance which handled the execution
   *  @param  results     The results, if any, returned from the database
   */
  ```

Comment: I don't see where I'm missing a `*`.  I intended use something to turn this into some nice looking Apple docs sometime, but haven't got around to it yet.

Comment: As for "Required", I *may* have copied this pattern from Apple's official documentation--I'll double check.  If not, I'll implement this change.

Comment: As for `readonly`, "Do we really want the API users to have the ability to change the username or server variables after initialization?"  Yes, actually, which suggests to me I might need better documentation and comments on this matter.